# How to execute R inside snakemake

Tags: r, snakemake

I find the snakemake [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#external-scripts) quite terse. Since I've been asked this a few times I thought posting the question and my own answer.

How do you execute or integrate this R script in a snakemake rule?

`my-script.R`

```r
CUTOFF <- 25

dat <- read.table('input-table.txt')

out <- dat[dat$V1 > CUTOFF, ]

write.table(out, 'output-table.txt')
```

Snakefile:

```
rule one:
    input:
        txt= 'input-table.txt',
    output:
        out= 'output-table.txt',
    params:
        cutoff= 25,
    # now what?
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to propose three solutions, roughly in order from most canonical.

**OPTION 1**: Use the `script` directory in combination with the `snakemake` R object

Replace the actual filenames inside the R script with the S4 object `snakemake`
which holds input, output, params etc:

`my-script.R`

```r
CUTOFF <- snakemake@params[['cutoff']]

dat <- read.table(snakemake@input[['txt']])

out <- dat[dat$V1 > CUTOFF, ]

write.table(out, snakemake@output[['out']])
```

Similarly, wildcards values would be accessible via `snakemake@wildcards[['some-wildcard']]`

The rule would look like:

```
rule one:
    input:
        txt= 'input-table.txt',
    output:
        out= 'output-table.txt',
    params:
        cutoff= 25,
    script:
        '/path/to/my-script.R'
```

Note that the script filename must end in `.R` or `.r` to
instruct snakemake that this is an R script.

**Pros**

- This is the simplest option, just replace the actual filenames and parameters with `snakemake@...` in the R script

**Cons**

- You may have many short scripts that make the pipeline difficult to follow.
  What does `my-script.R` actually do?
- `--printshellcmds` option is not helpful here
- Debugging the R script may be cluncky because of the embedded `snakemake` object

---

**OPTION 2:** Write a standalone R script executable via `shell` directive

For example using the [argparse](https://github.com/trevorld/r-argparse) library for R:

`my-script.R`

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(argparse)

parser <- ArgumentParser(description= 'This progrom does stuff')

parser$add_argument('--input', '-i', help= 'I am the input file')
parser$add_argument('--output', '-o', help= 'I am the output file')
parser$add_argument('--cutoff', '-c', help= 'Some filtering cutoff', type= 'double')

xargs<- parser$parse_args()

CUTOFF <- xargs$cutoff
dat <- read.table(xargs$input)
out <- dat[dat$V1 > CUTOFF, ]
write.table(out, xargs$output)
```

The snakemake rule is like any other one executing shell commands:

```
rule one:
    input:
        txt= 'input-table.txt',
    output:
        out= 'output-table.txt',
    params:
        cutoff= 25,
    shell:
        r"""
        /path/to/my-script.R --input {input.txt} --output {output.out} --cutoff {params.cutoff}
        """
```

**Pros**

- You get a standalone, nicely documented script that you can use elsewhere
- `--printshellcmds` tells you what is being executed and you can re-run it outside snakemake

**Cons**

- Some setting up to do via `argparse`
- Not so easy to debug by opening the R interpreter and running the individual R commands

---

**OPTION 3** Create a temporary R script as an [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) that you run via Rscript:

This is all self-contained in the rule:

```
rule one:
    input:
        txt= 'input-table.txt',
    output:
        out= 'output-table.txt',
    params:
        cutoff= 25,
    shell:
        r"""
cat <<'EOF' > {rule}.$$.tmp.R

CUTOFF <- {params.cutoff}
dat <- read.table('{input.txt}')
out <- dat[dat$V1 > CUTOFF, ]
write.table(out, '{output.out}')

EOF
Rscript {rule}.$$.tmp.R
rm {rule}.$$.tmp.R
        """
```

Explanantion: The syntax `cat <<'EOF'` tells Bash that everything until the EOF
marker is a string to be written to file `{rule}.$$.tmp.R`. Before running this
shell script, snakemake will replace the placeholders `{...}` as usual. So file
`{rule}.$$.tmp.R` will be `one.$$.tmp.R` where bash will replace `$$` with the
current process ID. The combination of `{rule}` and `$$` reasonably ensures
that each temporary R script has a distinct filename. NB: `EOF` is not a special
keyword, you can use any marker string to delimit the heredoc.

The content of `{rule}.$$.tmp.R` will be:

```
CUTOFF <- 25
dat <- read.table('input-table.txt')
out <- dat[dat$V1 > CUTOFF, ]
write.table(out, 'output-table.txt')
```

after execution via Rscript, `{rule}.$$.tmp.R` will be deleted by `rm` provided
that Rscripts exited clean.

**Pros**

- Especially for short scripts, you see what the rule actually does. No
  need to look into other script files.
- `--printshellcmds` option shows the exact R code. You can copy & paste it
  to the R interpreter as it is which is very useful for debugging and developing

**Cons**

- Clunky, quite a bit of boiler plate code
- If input/output/params are lists, you need to split them with e.g.
  `strsplit('{params}', sep= ' ')` inside the R script. This is not great
  especially if you have space inside the list items.
- If Rscript fails the temp R script is not deleted and it litters your working
  dir.

Comment: Option 2 seems the clearest by far in terms of reproducibility allowing for deployment on different systems.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a simple template for running snakemake with R - here's the Github link:

https://github.com/fritzbayer/snakemake-with-R

It shows two simple options for passing variables between snakemake and R.

Answer (score 1):

[@dariober has a thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68620783/570918). I wanted to share the variation on Option 1 that I use to make interactive development/debugging of R scripts a bit easier.

### Mock `snakemake` Object

One can include a preamble to create a mock `snakemake` object conditioned on whether the script is run interactively or not. This mimics the actual object that gets instantiated, enabling one to step through the code with a realistic input, but gets skipped over when Snakemake is executing the script.

**scripts/my-script.R**

```r
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

################################################################################
## Mock `snakemake` preamble
################################################################################

if (interactive()) {
  library(methods)
  Snakemake <- setClass(
    "Snakemake", 
    slots=c(
      input='list', 
      output='list', 
      params='list',
      threads='numeric'
    )
  )
  snakemake <- Snakemake(
    input=list(txt="input-table.txt"),
    output=list(out="output-table.txt"),
    params=list(cutoff=25),
    threads=1
  )
}

################################################################################

CUTOFF <- snakemake@params$cutoff

dat <- read.table(snakemake@input$txt)

out <- dat[dat$V1 > CUTOFF, ]

write.table(out, snakemake@output$out)
```

#### Object Details

The full set of slots on the `Snakemake` class can be seen in [the `generate_preamble` code](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/f0e8fa285437a02ca7edcf87334bf00cb347064a/snakemake/script.py#L595) from the `snakemake.script.Rscript` class. Since this is subject to change, one can inspect the code in the installed version using (from Python where Snakemake is installed):

```python
from inspect import getsource
from snakemake.script import RScript

print(getsource(RScript.generate_preamble))
```