# A question when insert running Rscript in Snakemake

Tags: snakemake, rscript

I write a snakemake containing Rscript for plotting, like:

```
rule R_drawing:
    input:
        "XXX.tsv"
    output:
        "XXX.pdf"
    script:
        "./Tail.R"
```

The Rscript use ggplot2 for drawing and save pdf by using ggsave. (I save the plot as a variation so there is not problem about plotting in screen)

When I typr my R code in shell R, it run well and finish within 1 minute.
But when I run the snakemake, it shows that although there are 'library' information and ggplot information I also met in shell print in screen, it cost much time (it feel that it stuck in some steps).
Finally it cost 2 hours and the output seem that the drawing is odd: the size of it is pretty larger that normal and the plot seem that some drawing has been plot many time.
I doubt it may be the error from multi cpu but when I changed `-c1`, the problem still occur.

SO I hope to receive some advise from every friend.Thanks!

Here is an example:

Snakemake:

```
rule polyA_results:
    input:
        "./{example}/analysis/polyA_estimate/header.tsv",
        "./{example}/analysis/polyA_estimate/polya_results.pass_only.tsv"
    output:
        "./{example}/analysis/polyA_estimate/polyA_estimate.tsv"
    shell:
        "cat {input[0]} {input[1]} > {output}"

rule R_drawing:
    input:
        "./{example}/analysis/polyA_estimate/polyA_estimate.tsv"
    output:
        "./{example}/analysis/polyA_estimate/polyA_estimate.pdf"
    script:
        "./Tail.R"
```

The Rscript

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(viridis)
library(cowplot)
library(showtext)
font_add('Arial','/usr/share/fonts/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf')
showtext_auto() 

percontig <- read.csv(snakemake@input[[1]],sep = "\t",header = F)
contigsummary <- aggregate(percontig$V9,by=list(type=percontig$V2),mean)
contigsummary$y <- c("plus")


p1 <- ggplot(contigsummary) +
  geom_violin(mapping = aes(x=contigsummary$y,y=contigsummary$x),width=0.6,fill="#5A005A") + 
  geom_boxplot(mapping=aes(x=contigsummary$y,y=contigsummary$x), color="grey",width=0.1, alpha=0.2) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.title = element_text(size=16,hjust = 0.5),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, family = "myFont", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=13, face="plain" , vjust = 10.2, hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=13, face="plain" ,  hjust = 0.5),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black")
  ) +
  ggtitle("Poly(A) Length of Reads") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Reads") +
  ylab("Poly(A) Length (nt)")



p2 <- ggplot(percontig) + 
  geom_violin(mapping = aes(x=percontig$V10,y=percontig$V9),width=0.6,fill="#316397")+
  geom_boxplot(mapping=aes(x=percontig$V10,y=percontig$V9), color="grey",width=0.1, alpha=0.2) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.title = element_text(size=16,hjust = 0.5),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, family = "myFont", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=13, face="plain" , vjust = 10.2, hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=13, face="plain" , hjust = 0.5),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black")
  ) +
  ggtitle("Poly(A) Length of Contigs") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Contigs") +
  ylab("Poly(A) Length (nt)")

p3 <- cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 2,labels = LETTERS[1:2])

ggsave(snakemake@output[[1]],p3,width = 20, height = 20)
```

Comment: You need to give more information. Try to write a minimum example. At least we need to see the the snakemake portion that is used to generate the figure, the R code and the input for the R code.

Comment: Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68620638/how-to-execute-r-inside-snakemake) about running R in Snakemake. Also, you don't have to include "./" in your snakefile.